# overlayCloseButton not triggering toggleFullScreen funitonality when using viewer.js [which internally using pdf.js]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sitefinity, pdf.js

I am using viewer.js to view the pdf . pdf file is viewing correctly other then that after clicking presentation link when i try to click X [which is overlayCloseButton div] nothing happens. probably toggleFullScreen is not working correctly.
I have checked it in chrome, IE10 and FF

Please let me know what can i do to let it working

Comment: What are the error messages? Please notice that if you place something that requires full screen in IFRAME you have to specify (moz|webkit|)allowfullscreen attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails

Comment: nothing happens after i click it. don't know how can i put this attribute on iframe.haven't find any example there with using iframe. I will try putting it like
<iframe ... mozallowfullscreen="true"

Comment: so you are using iframe... okay. <iframe src="..." width="..." height="..." frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: as mentioned i am using viewerjs which have to use iframe. that's why i am using iframe.
After doing this it is now working correctly in Chrome and FF. But not in IE

Comment: Also one thing about fullscreen problem in IE is that markup in IE i  
<button title="Fullscreen" class="toolbarButton fullscreen" id="fullscreen" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>


While in FF it is 
<button id="fullscreen" class="toolbarButton fullscreen" title="Fullscreen"></button>

And in Chrome it is appearing as 

<button id="fullscreen" class="toolbarButton fullscreen" title="Fullscreen">::before</button>

Comment: And css in viewer.css is
.toolbarButton.fullscreen::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: url(images/toolbarButton-fullscreen.png);
}

Comment: Not sure how styling of the fullscreen button related to the functionality of the requestFullscreen. I don't think it's a PDF.js issue. Check IE restrictions on using requestFullscreen in the IFRAME.

Comment: Find out that full screen API is not supported in IE till there version 10. Thought there might be some functionality there in pdf.js that if IE version is less then 11 then hide full screen option

Comment: Report that to the issue tracker with steps to replicate... or better submit a pull request